# Filtering dataframe results

Tags: r

I want to filter values as displaying specified columns.

For example;

```
iris[iris$Sepal.Length > 6, ]
```

code is returning me the sepal length values are higher than "6" with whole columns. How can I narrow it to show sepal.length and sepal.width values with whose species are virginica and versicolor for example?

Comment: Look into using `%in%` on the species column in a similar way to your example above.

Comment: You need `&` (vector "and") and `%in%`, as in `iris[iris$Sepal.Length > 6 & iris$Species %in% c("virginica", "versicolor"), c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")]`

Comment: Realize that adding a filter to just those two `Species` in this case is a no-op, as only those species are long enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R:

```r
head(iris[iris$Sepal.Length > 6 & iris$Species %in% c("virginica", "versicolor"), c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")])
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
# 51          7.0         3.2
# 52          6.4         3.2
# 53          6.9         3.1
# 55          6.5         2.8
# 57          6.3         3.3
# 59          6.6         2.9
```

Dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length > 6, Species %in% c("virginica", "versicolor")) %>%
  select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>%
  head()
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
# 1          7.0         3.2
# 2          6.4         3.2
# 3          6.9         3.1
# 4          6.5         2.8
# 5          6.3         3.3
# 6          6.6         2.9
```

Data.table:

```r
library(data.table)
data(iris)
setDT(iris)
head(iris[ Sepal.Length > 6 & Species %in% c("virginica", "versicolor"), 
           .(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) ])
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
# 1:          7.0         3.2
# 2:          6.4         3.2
# 3:          6.9         3.1
# 4:          6.5         2.8
# 5:          6.3         3.3
# 6:          6.6         2.9
```